# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value while fetching PHAsset Path

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, phasset

App crashes due to nil value in code on line :

```
if let strURL = (contentEditingInput!.audiovisualAsset as? AVURLAsset)?.url.absoluteString
```

Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
func getUrlFromPHAsset(asset: PHAsset, callBack: @escaping (_ url: URL?) -> Void) {
    asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions(), completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, dictInfo) in

        if let strURL = (contentEditingInput!.audiovisualAsset as? AVURLAsset)?.url.absoluteString {
            print("VIDEO URL: \(strURL)")
            callBack(URL.init(string: strURL))
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but this implicitly unwrapped optional is unsafe: `contentEditingInput!`. Is that what's nil? it would be safer to have that line as:

```
if let strURL = (contentEditingInput?.audiovisualAsset as? AVURLAsset)?.url.absoluteString
```

Otherwise, if `contentEditingInput` is nil, you'll crash when it's unwrapped.

For future reference, please try to provide more information about where the crash is occurring, related code, and what the values are that are used in the code shown.

Comment: yes i am getting contentEditingInput as nil. I have already used if else part but still giving error

Comment: The difference in my code above is the "?" after `contentEditingInput`. If that value is nil, evaluation will stop rather than crash.